# How to create a Custom Scheduler in Sugar versions less than 6.3?

Tags: sugarcrm

I know how to code to create a custom scheduler for Sugar versions greater than 6.3 , using Ext framework but that is not working 6.1 Pro Version.
I also tried creating custom scheduler in custom/modules/Scheduler/_AddJobsHere.php but even that is not working in 6.1 Pro Version.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place your file over here

custom/modules/Schedulers/_AddJobsHere.php

instead of

custom/modules/Scheduler/_AddJobsHere.php

module name **Schedulers** not Scheduler,

Then it should work.